# error to installing sass with gem in windows 8.1

Tags: ruby, windows, sass

I'm installing ruby in windows 8.1 pro

```
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x64-mingw32]
```

and gem version

```
2.2.2
```

when in execute the gem installation throw this error :

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (ArgumentError)
        unknown encoding name - CP720
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: it's can't be solve, even if i change my windows operatin?nobody can help me

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This command will fix it -- you need to change the code page of the current terminal.

```
chcp 1252
```

Comment: If you use Mingw in Windows, it will output "command not found" error. Instead modify the command a little: chcp.com 1252 (assuming you have installed your system directory to your PATH variable)

Answer (score -3):

Try to uninstall ruby and re-install a previous version. that worked for me once.

another solution is to type this in cmd:     `set = HTTP_proxy http://10.1.143.126:3128`     and try again

- don't forget to run cmd as administrator.