# How to Fix Error When Updating Ruby Gems 2.2.3 on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the error:

```
ERROR : loading commend: install (ArgumentError)
                 unkoun encoding name - CP720
ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
                undefined method 'invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

When I try to update Rails with:

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error to installing sass with gem in windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782334/error-to-installing-sass-with-gem-in-windows-8-1)

not necessarily a duplicate, but the answer should solve your problem here.