# SASS installation error: undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Tags: sass

I've installed RUBY at first but when I try to install SASS

```
gem install sass
```

I have the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaP0V.pngP0V.png):

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (ArgumentError)
        unknown encoding name - CP720
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error to installing sass with gem in windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782334/error-to-installing-sass-with-gem-in-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code page of the current terminal window running this code:

```
chcp 1252
```