# Error while installing Rails gem on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails on Windows. After successfully installing Ruby, when I run `ruby -v` , it returns `ruby 2.4.4` as expected. The `gem` application is installed and is version 2.77. But when I try executing the command:

```
gem install rails
```

it gives the following error:

```
C:\>gem install rails
ERROR:  Loading command: install (ArgumentError)
        unknown encoding name - CP720
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I fix this error so I can install Ruby on Rails on Windows?

Comment: Do not make a screenshot of your console. Copy and paste the relevant text into your question so that others can search for and find this question and its accepted answer. The only useful diagnostic information is in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782334/error-to-installing-sass-with-gem-in-windows-8-1)

Run this command:

```
chcp 1252
```

And run your command again.